# Spring Boot 2.2.4 - disable security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security

I found a massive amount of blog posts and questions on stackoverflow on how to disable security in spring boot - but none of it seems to work with spring boot 2.2.4.

I'm asking because I want to configuratively disable security for my dev and test profile so that we can deploy without generating jwt tokens all the time.

The most promising approach from my perspective is to exclude the `SecurityAutoConfiguration` class via the properties file but as said the exclusion has no effect.

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration
```

The other properties such as `management.security.enabled` seem to be deprecated.

Comment: Exclude the auto-config and enable yourself based on the profile. Also for security there are multiple exclusion especially if doing oauth or manually configuring security (which you appear to do due to the fact that you use JWT).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a working solution in the spring boot github issues.

Disable security for the entire application:

```
@SpringBootApplication ( exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class} )
@Import(MySecurityConfiguration.class)
public class MyApplication{
 }
```

... and enable via parameter in the security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty (  "my.security.enabled" )
@Import ( SecurityAutoConfiguration.class 
public class MySecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

}
```

Source: [https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12323#issuecomment-370519882](http://@Configuration%20@ConditionalOnProperty%20(%20%20%22my.security.enabled%22%20)%20@Import%20(%20SecurityAutoConfiguration.class%20%20public%20class%20MySecurityConfiguration%20extends%20WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter%20%7B%20%20%7D)

Comment: If someone is just trying to disable security, the second part (along with Import on MyApplication) is not even needed. Just fyi.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter Bean for your profile containing following overriden method implementation, to exclude all endpoints from spring security:

```java
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(
                "/**"
        );
    }
```